# Careers - can't save my details

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, employers

Using this URL...

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/info?returnUrl=%2faccount

I can't save my details, and there is no reason (validation messages) as to why.

Comment: Confirmed - will look into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a bug.  It has been fixed and will go out with the next push, which should be in the next few hours.